# Is it possible to get multiple sets of rows, each containing a limited number of rows, filtered by a column in a table in Django/SQL?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

Sorry the question is so confusing, I couldn't find a way to word it better. This is better explained with an example:

I have an Image model linked to a Game model. Each Image has a category (the categories are fixed and number about 10). I want to get 3 images of each category (or less, if there aren't enough) for a game.

This is the current implementation:

```
from django.db import models 

class Game(models.Model):
    ... 

class Image(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)

    @classmethod 
    def categories(cls):
        return ('category1', 'category2', ...)

    @classmethod 
    def get_game_images(cls, game:Game):
        return [cls.objects.filter(game=game, category=category)
                for category in cls.categories()]

# Do stuff with the images
game = Game.objects.all().first()
for category in Image.get_game_images(game):
    print(category)
    for image in category: 
        print('\t', image.image.url)
```

I feel a bit dumb doing 10 very similar queries to retrieve 3 elements each... A simple `Image.objects.filter(game=game).order_by('category')` gets close, but then ensuring there are only 3 rows per category becomes a bit complex. Is there a better way to accomplish the same result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single query that makes a *union* of certain subqueries:

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet

# …

    @classmethod 
    def get_game_images(cls, game:Game):
        QuerySet.union(
            *[cls.objects.filter(game=game, category=category)[:3]
              for category in cls.categories()]
        )
```

This thus will make *one* query, and furthermore the `QuerySet` is *lazy* so if you do not enumerate over it, call `len(…)` on it, etc. it will not make the query.

The `[:3]` at the end means we will fetch at most three objects for that `game` and `category`.